# How to set absolute path?

Tags: java, vert.x

```
netServerOptions
    .setSsl(true)
    .setKeyStoreOptions(new JksOptions()
        .setPath("keystore.jks")
        .setPassword("hello!"));
```

I want to set path "/home/keystore.jks".

I want to change readFileSync absolute path. /keystore.jks -> /usr/local/jks/keystore.jks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store can either be loaded by Vert.x from the filesystem:

HttpServerOptions options = HttpServerOptions.httpServerOptions();
 options.setKeyStore(new JKSOptions().setPath("/mykeystore.jks").setPassword("foo"));

Or directly provided as a buffer:
 Buffer store = vertx.fileSystem().readFileSync("/mykeystore.jks");
 options.setKeyStore(new JKSOptions().setValue(store).setPassword("foo"));

Comment: I want to change readFileSync absolute path.
/mykeystore.jks -> /usr/local/jks